# How to build modular js promise chains?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, promise, q

I have a promise chain that is currently running with very basic error handling. If a step fails, the subsequent steps will not run. I want to be able to continue the promise chain at a later time if there is a failure, and it should start from where it left off.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
// controller.js
var failure = false;
QueryFactory.step1()                      // Step 1
   .then(function(msg){
      if(failure == false){
        console.log("Finished Step 1");
        return QueryFactory.step2();
      }
   }, function(err){
      console.log(err);
      failure = true;
   })
   .then(function(msg){                   // Step 2
      if(failure == false){
         console.log("Finished Step 2");
         return QueryFactory.step3();
      }
   }, function(err){
      console.log(err);
      failure = true;
   })
   .then(function(msg){                   // Step 3
      if(failure == false){
         console.log("Finished Step 3");
      }
   }, function(err){
      console.log(err);
      failure = true;
   })
```

And my factory looks like this:

```
// QueryFactory.js
step1 = function(){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.post('/task', {step_num: 1})
      .then(function(data)){
         deferred.resolve(data);
      }, function(err){
         deferred.reject(err);
      });
   return deferred.promise;
}
// step2 and step3 are similar
```

But perhaps there is a better way of writing this to allow for modularity? Say step2 were to fail, how can I design a way so that a user can click a button to later continue the chain from step2?

Comment: Your "chain" doesn't pass any data from any step to the following step. Also, they will all execute one after the other, regardless of "success" or "failure".

Comment: So how do you recommend I do this correctly?

Comment: First of all, avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [difference between `.then(…).catch(…)` and `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572). In your case, by passing the second callback to `then`, you'd eventually step over the current step instead of continuing where you left off. What you are looking for is

```
QueryFactory.step1()
.then(function(msg) {
    console.log("Finished Step 1 without error");
    return msg;
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    …
}).then(function() {
    return QueryFactory.step2();
}).then(function(msg) {
    console.log("Finished Step 2 without error");
    return msg;
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    …
}).then(function() {
    return QueryFactory.step3();
}).then(function(msg) {
    console.log("Finished Step 3 without error");
    return msg;
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    …
}).then(function(res) {
    console.log("everything is finished");
}).catch(function(err){
    console.error("something bad happened", err);
});
```

(Alternatively you can use a plain `.catch` instead of the `then` with the callback that tells you whether a step finished without error, if you don't need those logs)

Now, what are these `…` in the code? It's for your requirement

> I want to be able to continue the promise chain at a later time if there is a failure

In the `…` sections, you will need to *handle* the error, and return a promise for error-free result of the step that failed, e.g. by retrying. This promise would only settle at that "later time" - you can wait for a user confirmation of the error, a timeout, or whatever you want.

Once that promise you returned from the error callback settles, the chain will continue.